# Numbers of reflections on a coset in reflection group

Tags: reflection-groups

Consider $G_{k}$ a group of type Shephard–Todd. Given a reflection  $\sigma \in G_{k}$, take $H$ the subgroup generated by $\sigma$. How to determine the number of reflections in the coset $\tau \cdot H$, where $\tau \in G_{k} \setminus H$.

I tried to determine this number with package CHEVIE on gap3. But I don't have much practice with the gap at the moment.